# SQL - How to return n biggest based on count condition?

Tags: sql

The example table i have:

```
id    name
1     buy
1     sell
1     trade
2     buy
2     buy
3     sell
4     sell
```

How can i make a condition to return n of the toppest ids that most appeared?
For example, if i want just the id who most appeared, it would be just id 1. If i wanted the 2 ids that most appeared, would be returning just lines with id 1 or 2.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

If you want *id*s, then aggregate and limit the results:

```
select id
from t
group by id
order by count(*) desc 
offset 0 fetch first <n> rows only;
```

`<n>` is the value you care about.  If you want the original rows, you can use the above with `in` or a `join`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.id in (select t2.id
               from t t2
               group by id
               order by count(*) desc 
               offset 0 fetch first <n> rows only
              );
```

Note that not all databases support the Standard SQL `fetch first` clause.  You may need to use `limit` or `select top` or some other mechanism.

Comment: Also note that `offset 0` isn't needed at all, unless your using MS SQL Server you can simply do `fetch first <n> rows only`.